# Searching list of items in a list

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Initially i have following code.

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
list.Add("abcd", 1);
list.Add("abc", 12);
list.Add("def", 14);
```

//Finding items on this list is simple.

```
var results = list.Where(p => p.Value.Equals("abc"));
```

Here comes my question.

If i have a list of search words, how to search those items in list. I don't want to use for loop for this. Is there any built-in functionality or I need to write an extension method?

```
List<string> searchList = new List<string>();
searchList.Add("abc") ;
searchList.Add("def") ;
```

Find all items in `searchList` in `list`

Comment: should "abc" in you search list match both "abc" and "abcd"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface:

```
public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return y.Contains(x);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
        HashSet<string> searchList = new HashSet<string>();
        searchList.Add("abc");
        searchList.Add("def");

        var list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        list.Add("abcd", 1);
        list.Add("abc", 12);
        list.Add("def abc", 14);
        list.Add("test test", 15);

        var lst = list.Where(p => searchList.Contains(p.Key, new EqualityComparer()));
```

As @Ani said this equality is not good you can also do:

```
var lst1 = list.Where(p => searchList.Any(x => p.Key.Contains(x)));
```

Just add null checkings yourself.

Comment: I would strongly caution against writing such an IEqualityComparer. It fails a property as basic as symmetry:  `Equals(a, b) => Equals(b, a)`.

Comment: @Ani, this is equality implicitly defined by question, I don't know there is better solution with this order and saving this equality or not (and I didn't think about it), I know you want to refer me to msdn, but this equality used for this purpose and with name line ContainEquality it will be distinguished from general equality.

Comment: Sure; I just thought it was important for readers to note. They might run into problems if they used it for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a HashSet for your searchList and then doing something like this:

```
HashSet<string> searchList = new HashSet<string>();
searchList.Add("abc");
searchList.Add("def");

var list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
list.Add("abcd", 1);
list.Add("abc", 12);
list.Add("def", 14);

list.Where(p => searchList.Contains(p.Key));
```

This will prevent an O(n) operation on the searchList for each execution of the Where clause as the lookup should be close to O(1)

Comment: it is matching the content with search item, so if list has "abc def" and searchList has item "def", it did not find it.

Comment: I see, then I think the approach here is incorrect.  If you need to have a proper searching algorithm, I'd rethink this approach and potentially looking at having a simple indexing of your searchable items.